# How good is startswith?

Tags: python

Is

```
text.startswith('a')
```

better than

```
text[0]=='a'
```

?

Knowing text is not empty and we are only interested in the first character of it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I'd agree with the others that startswith is more readable, and you should use that.  That said, if performance is a big issue for such a special case, benchmark it:

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'text="foo"' 'text.startswith("a")'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.537 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit -s 'text="foo"' 'text[0]=="a"'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.22 usec per loop
```

So `text[0]` is amost 2.5 times as fast - but it's a pretty quick operation; you'd save ~0.3 microseconds per compare depending on the system.  Unless you're doing millions of comparisons in a time critical situation though, I'd still go with the more readable startswith.

Comment: To affirm this I shaved 12 seconds (from 15s to less than 2s) from a function just by changing `text[index:].startswith(b'test')` to `text[index:index+4] == b'test'`

Answer (score 33):

`text[0]` fails if `text` is an empty string:

```
IronPython 2.6 Alpha (2.6.0.1) on .NET 4.0.20506.1
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> text = ""
>>> print(text.startswith("a"))
False
>>> print(text[0]=='a')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: index out of range: 0
```

EDIT: You say you "know" that `text` is not empty... how confident are you of that, and what would you want to happen if it *is* empty in reality? If a failure is appropriate (e.g. it means a bug in your code) that would encourage the use of `text[0]=='a'`.

Other questions:

- How concerned are you about the performance of this? If this is performance critical, then benchmark it *on your particular Python runtime*. I wouldn't be *entirely* surprised to find that (say) one form was faster on IronPython and a different one faster on CPython.
- Which do *you* (and your team) find more readable?

Comment: Sorry I didn't say that I know that text is not empty.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: True, but that can be cirumvented with saying `text[:1]` instead.

Comment: @balpha: But that's a different question then :)

Comment: True. Just felt it should be mentioned, because (at least in a naive test I just ran), slicing in fact *is* a lot faster than `startswith`; so if performance is important, it might help to know this.

Comment: @balpha: A lot faster on what runtime? Not that I'm an expert on Python performance (by a long way!) but I'd expect the performance characteristics to change immensely between implementations.

Comment: Good point. I used CPython. But as I said, it was just a very naive test. If performance is an issue, the particular case should be measured & optimized anyway; if not, readability counts---which is definitely a point for `startswith`. Anyhow, +1 on your edit.

Answer (score 11):

Personally I would say `startswith` is more readable.

Also, from Python 2.5 `startwith` can take a tuple of prefixes to look for:

```
>>> "hello world".startswith(("hello","goodbye"))
True
```

Answer (score 11):

Yes: it’s easier to use and easier to read. When you are testing for more than one letter, when using slicing, you’ll have to know how long the target text is:

```
haystack = 'Hello, World!'
needle = 'Hello'

# The easy way
result = haystack.startswith(needle)

# The slightly harder way
result = haystack[:len(needle)] == needle
```

**Edit:** The question seems to have changed. It now says, “knowing text is not empty and we are only interested in the first character of it.” That turns it into a fairly meaningless hypothetical situation.

I suspect the questioner is trying to “optimize” his/her code for execution speed. If that is the case, my answer is: don’t. Use whichever form is more *readable* and, therefore, more maintainable when you have to come back and work on it a year from now. Only optimize if profiling shows that line of code to be the bottleneck. This is not some O(n²) algorithm. It’s a string comparison.

Comment: The question is really about testing the first letter.

Comment: I've hit this exact issue in a non-hypothetical use case; effectively I had a mapping that proxied to one dictionary if you requested a key starting with ~, and another dictionary for every other character. It was called tens of thousands to millions of times, and in particular was called for redrawing dirty parts of a window when a mouse moved over it (a GTK+ virtual list model column), so it needed to be extremely efficient.

Since I didn't know the string was non-empty, I used [:1]; as suggested below it was still twice as fast as startsWith.

Answer (score 11):

[PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) explicitly tells to use `startswith`, because of readability:

> Use `''.startswith()` and `''.endswith()` instead of string
> slicing to check
> for prefixes or suffixes.
>
> startswith() and endswith() are cleaner and less error prone:
>
> ```
>     Yes: if foo.startswith('bar'):
>
>     No:  if foo[:3] == 'bar':
> ```

Answer (score 8):

`text[0]` can fail but the equivalent `text[:1]` is safe if the string is empty.

If you want to compare more than one character, I believe `.startswith()` is better.

Answer (score 6):

The stock phrase for the questiom is: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil".

Comment: So, which one would you use ?

Comment: text.startswith('a'). It clearly tells what you want to achieve.
I can only think of text[0] == 'a' as an alternative, as a way of saving a few cpu cycles.

Comment: Selective quotation. Read the whole paragraph in which that clause is embedded. It's not even a complete sentence in the original.

Answer (score 2):

```
def compo2():
    n = "abba"
    for i in range(1000000):
        n[:1]=="_"
```

is faster than

```
def compo():
    n = "abba"
    for i in range(1000000):
        n.startswith("_")
```

cProfile reports 0.061 for `compo2` compared to 0.954 for `compo` on my machine.
This of interest in case you want to make a LOT of prefix checks for various "_mystring".
If most strings don't start with underscores then using `string[:1]== char` before using `startswith` is an option to optimize your code.
In a real application this method saved me about 15% of cpu time.

Answer (score 1):

text[0]=='a' is good considering performance. Also you need to add validation when you use this.

Answer (score 0):

My ideas:

- `startswith` can work with any length, can work with empty strings, I prefer this.
- indexing can only work if the length is specified, cannot work with empty strings.