# pythonic way to combine a lot of startswith statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, startswith

What is the "pythonic" way to combine a lot of `startswith` statements?

Here are the details:
I receive various types of messages from a server, which sends them with different first letters in order for receiver to quickly identify and sort them. I wrote a code with a lot of

```
if message.startswith('A'):
   do_A()
elif message.startswith('B'):
   do_B()
```

- like statements. However, I feel there is more pythonic way to write the code without many statements, like maybe to make a list of all possible first letters and have one `startswith` statement.

Other variants with `if message[0]=='A'` are even better, since it appears to be faster per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1316245/4383472), and speed matters to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a dictionary mapping first letter to a function:

```
message_map = {'A': do_A, 'B': do_B}
dispatch = message_map.get(message[:1])
if dispatch is not None:
    dispatch()
```

Functions in Python are first-class objects, so you can store them in a dictionary like this.

Note that I used a slice to get the first character; it'll result in an empty string if `message` happens to be empty, rather than throw an `IndexError` exception.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Also question as to performance: with `if elif` the test stops as soon as it finds that it is 'A'-kind of message, and i have 70% of 'A' messages. Will there be loss of performance with the use of dictionary (since dict is unsorted)? Speed matters because there are hundreds/thousands messages per sec

Comment: @Bad dictionary lookups are very fast, faster than `if` branching, as they take O(1) constant time.