# What is the fastest way to compare beginning of a string?

Tags: python, regex

Imagine list of strings like this one: `('{hello world} is awesome', 'Hello world is less awesome', '{hello world} is {awesome} too')`. I want to check each string in for cycle for starting character, I think I have got 4 options:

```
if re.search(r'^\{', i):
if re.match(r'\{', i):
if i.startswith('{'):
if i[:1] == '{':
```

Which is the fastest one? Is there some even more faster than these 4 options?

Note: The starting string to compare could be longer, not only one letter, e.g. `{hello`

Comment: Why don't you time them and see? Anyhow, seems like premature optimization. IMO, `startswith()` is most readable.

Comment: Use `timeit` and see which method faster..

Comment: The last test should be `i[0] == '{'`

Comment: `if i[0] == '{':` takes on the order of 1/5 usec according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315559/how-good-is-startswith.  You're not going to get better than that

Comment: @MosesKoledoye @PatrickHaugh Can I use something like `i[0]` for multiple characters? (like `if i[:6] == '{hello':`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @dsqdfg said in the comments, there is a timing function in python I've never known until now. I tried to measure them and there are some results:

```
python -m timeit -s 'text="{hello world}"' 'text[:6] == "{hello"'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.224 usec per loop
```

---

```
python -m timeit -s 'text="{hello world}"' 'text.startswith("{hello")'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.291 usec per loop
```

---

```
python -m timeit -s 'text="{hello world}"' 'import re' 're.match(r"\{hello", text)'
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.53 usec per loop
```

---

```
python -m timeit -s 'text="{hello world}"' 'import re' 're.search(r"^\{hello", text)'
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.86 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 4):

The fastest is `i[0] == value`, since it directly uses a pointer to the underlying array. Regex needs to (at least) parse the pattern, while `startsWith` has the overhead of a method call and creating a slice of that size before the actual comparison.

Comment: Can I use something like `i[0]` for multiple characters? (like `if i[:6] == '{hello':`)

Comment: Yes. Slicing produces a string, which can be compared with the == operator